# PHP4 session / object problem

Tags: php, class, php4

I have a weird problem with PHP4

I have a class which assigns a $_SESSION variable.

On the local dev server it works as:
$_SESSION['foo'] = $this->foo;
and I can access $_SESSION['foo'] as a string.

on the live server $_SESSION['foo'] is not a string but a serialized object? the same code?

Comment: $this->foo is just a string, I need in the SESSION

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found out that `$_SESSION['myvar']` becomes a global `$myvar`, and was being overritten by the instance variable `$myvar = new MyClass();`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know much about this, but as far i use PHP, PHP 4 have some problem with $_SESSION (and $_SERVER etc) variable(s) and you better stick with the old way creating & storing session (i forgot about it btw). And what make problem was it have bugs in it's Object Oriented model.

Then i stick with PHP 5 works fine, you should consider migrating your application into PHP 5 too :D